# How to access newly created Gitlab acount?

Tags: gitlab, repository

I created a completely new Gitlab account, initiated an empty private  project, uploaded the SSH key and wanted to connect to the repository within gitbash on my Windows 10 system but I always get the message:

```
> Permission denied (publickey).
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
> and the repository exists.
```

What can I do to make Gitlab let me into my own project??

Answer (score 0):

In some circumstances, you need to add a *deploy key* to your gitlab project. This link will help you set them up.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html#deploy-keys

Comment: I tried it with no success. I have to mention that i set up the project as a private project. Could that cause problem even when I am the owner of the project?

Comment: No, all my project are private and I do not run across this problem. On Windows, I use GitKraken successfully, which allows the creation of SSH key very easily within the app's configuration. These keys work well on GitLab.

Answer (score 0):

It was the SSH key itself. I generated it with PuTTYgen. I don't know what went wrong but when I followed the Gitlab instructions for generating the SSH key [Generating a new SSH key pair with ssh-keygen](https://gitlab.com/help/ssh/README#generating-a-new-ssh-key-pair)
it works.